# IDEA(Ultimate v.14.0) with scala plugin(v.1.1.1) do not compile test classes

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, scala-2.10

Today I have updated the scala-plugin to v.1.1.1 in IDEA Ultimate v.14.0 and now I can't execute tests via IDEA.
I get an exception: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: models.HelloWorldSpec** 
I noticed that test classes do not appears in 'target/scala-2.10/test-classes' after compilation via IDEA. But all good when I execute 'sbt clean compile test' in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved in release 1.1.2 of the IntelliJ Scala plugin, as of 21st November:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/update/index?pr=&updateId=17896